# Export used css selectors using Dust me selectors

Tags: css-selectors

After i click on clean , how do i export the used css into a css file?.I need a css "cleaner" that is able to find the used css and export in a css file.A free solution is prefered
[image]

Comment: What is "clean"?  Where are you getting this button from?

Comment: sorry i justforgot to add pic ...anyways picture has been added

Comment: No answers at the moment. A browser plugin solution to remove unused css would be really helpful. You may want to look at this related [hackernews thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7772061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

First of all to clean up your CSS , never use minified version of CSS as Dust me selectors is unable to process such files and store css files locally

After you click on Clean up you then click on save to get the cleansed css file

Comment: There is no "Save" button after you "Clean up". There is only an export button or close. What are you talking about? Screenshot plz